# append any text to a div using jquery without altering the text

Tags: jquery, html, plaintext

I receive text via SignalR and I can use console.log(s) to view the text perfectly.

I now have a console page, basically a scrolling div, I want to view text unaltered, but

```
$('#console').append(s);
```

keeps altering the text content.

sample content in chrome console:

```
09-09 11:04:36.11 tx:   <body>4384041
user_22BLE:
Ok am a man i live in lagos too</body>
09-09 11:04:36.11 tx:   <offline></offline>
```

it even retains the line breaks...

Comment: basically how do we mimic google chrome console formatting in a div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

encode from html entities then it show similar like console

```
function htmlEntity(rawStr){
var encodedStr = rawStr.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
   return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';';
});
    return encodedStr;
}
```

you can encode html entity from this function

try like this

```
$('#console').append(htmlEntity(s));
```

Comment: what would really be nice would be to get my div to look exactly like Google chrome console output, styles and all...any clues?

Comment: because we change '<' to &lt; it is not render by browser that why it works